# О морфемном и словообразовательном анализе слов

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор, историческое-словообразование

Как ответить на **дополнительные вопросы,** которые возникают при разборе слов?  В качестве  примера использован глагол ***пригорюниться***.

1. Почему в разных словарях предлагается **разный** морфемный и словообразовательный анализ ***пригорюниться***?  Какие варианты вы считаете **правильными**?
2. Почему морфемный разбор дается на многих ресурсах, а словообразовательный разбор **трудно найти**? Как **связаны** эти разборы между собой?
3. Какова **историческая схема** образования глагола ***горюниться*** от существительного ***горе***?
4. Как выбирается **способ словообразования** (приставочный или приставочно-постфиксальный)? Например: *смотреть — **при/смотреть/ся**, терпеть — **при/терпеть/ся**, но: горюниться — **при/горюниться.***
5. Какова стилистика ***пригорюниться*** в современных текстах? Какие глаголы могут **заменить** это слово?

**P. S.** Можно ответить **на любой вопрос**, который покажется интересным.

Comment: Начал писать ответ на 3. Перечитал вопрос. Надо прям **историческую** схему?

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Я имела в виду исторический (диахронный) морфемный анализ (разбор). Начнем с коня ГОР, родственные слова гореть, горький, горячий, и-е корень g*hor. А дальше - откуда суффиксы взялись (промежуточные слова).Доп. информация – когда существовало промежуточное слово. https://studfile.net/preview/3558917/page:3/

Comment: Что здесь интересного? (1) Судьба этих промежуточных форм (когда и почему) ушли из языка. (2) Возможно, такой исторический словообразовательный разбор (диахронный) совпадает с современным (синхронным) разбором,  но формально-структурным (не формально-семантическим). У вас – "микроморфемы") Разница между разборами не раз обсуждалась на форуме, также эта тема есть у Литневской https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p19

Comment: Интересная цитата из обсуждения:  "А что вы конкретно предлагаете? Изменить грамматику, отменить грамматику? Это все равно что отменить закон. Сейчас же начнется беззаконие".  То же самое можно сказать о правилах))  Свобода от правил – это обязанность соблюдать правила.https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148316/discussion-on-question-by-sharon-------

Comment: Вот я и соблюдаю, в глубь теорий лезть недосуг, поэтому ответ не пишется, а рассуждаю я "микроморфемами": не много слов в русском языке с суффиксом *-юн*, среди них
*вь**юн**, кашл**юн**, пят**юн**я... и гор**юн***. Потом добавились *-и* и *-ть*, но "горюнить" не прижилось (здесь есть наброски мыслей), пришлось зациклить слово на самого себя, то есть добавить *-ся*, вот и получилось "горюниться". Суффикс *-юн* мне очень нравится :) тоже мысли есть.

Comment: Там не так глубоко, всего лишь Литневская для школьников (одна страница).  // Из суффиксов я прежде всего вспомнила "болтун". // А не прижилось здесь целое семейство, что от него осталось-то! К тому же слова разговорные, малоупотребительные. Тоже мысли нужны...